My pc restarts (randomly problem is not cpu,cpu over heating,ram,psu,gpu)
My pc restarts it self in ubuntu.I install windows there no problems in windows but only in ubuntu.And psu is not fauilty I check it with multimeter,cpu cool all the time plus my cooling system is liquid cooled system, ram is not faulty either. What to do.
